# Is it possible to do pseudo-loop in Java EE Batch definition file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-batch, batch-processing

At the moment, one of my job definition files looks like below. The problem is that I would like to run many identical chunks (parallel queue processing), and in this case, I would have to duplicate, for example, 20 identical flows which differ only in id.

Is it possible to do it somehow programmatically or maybe there is some property that would be useful?

It is also not the problem to switch to Spring Batch if there is such possibility.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job id="socialJob" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/jobXML_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <step id="prepare" next="mySplit">
        <batchlet ref="myPreProcessor" />
    </step>
    <split id="mySplit">
        <flow id="s1">
            <step id="myStep1">
                <chunk item-count="1">
                    <reader ref="myReader" />
                    <processor ref="myProcessor" />
                    <writer ref="myWriter" />
                    <skippable-exception-classes>
                        <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                    </skippable-exception-classes>
                </chunk>
            </step>
        </flow>
        <flow id="s2">
            <step id="myStep2">
                <chunk item-count="1">
                    <reader ref="myReader" />
                    <processor ref="myProcessor" />
                    <writer ref="myWriter" />
                    <skippable-exception-classes>
                        <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                    </skippable-exception-classes>
                </chunk>
            </step>
        </flow>
    </split>
</job>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility to create abstract step and inherit from them.
 You can find all information in [5. Configuring a step#Inheriting from a Parent Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#InheritingFromParentStep)

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Batch, there is the ability to perform loops of steps.  However, per JSR-352's specification, there is no looping allowed in a JSR defined job.

Comment: This is a real pain as it only allows for simplistic scenarios in regards to chunking.